# Calculate disparity from disparity map

Tags: python, opencv, matching

I am trying to calculate the disparity using the disparity map I display using the code below. I currently get a
How do I limit the selected pixels to be in a certain area on the x,y-axis and the disparity value for the selected pixels.

Currently when I print the disparity I get a matrix that I cannot use to calculate the disparity. I use the formula D=bf/d where D is the distance, b is baseline, f is focal length and d is the disparity. I know the baseline, focal length and actual distance but I can't get the correct distance using the disparity map.

How do I implement this into my code?

If it help I have the k-matrix from the camera calibration, however I don't know how to use it in my code.

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def main():
    print('loading images...')
    imgL = cv.imread('00004l.png')
    imgR = cv.imread('00004r.png')

    #Disparity settings
    window_size = 5
    min_disp = 16
    num_disp = 112-min_disp
    matcher_left = cv.StereoSGBM_create(
        blockSize = 5,
        numDisparities = num_disp,
        minDisparity = min_disp,
        P1 = 8*3*window_size**2,
        P2 = 32*3*window_size**2,
        disp12MaxDiff = 10,
        uniquenessRatio = 10,
        speckleWindowSize = 100,
        speckleRange = 5,
        preFilterCap=1,
        mode=cv.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
    )

    matcher_right = cv.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(matcher_left)

    # Filter
    lmbda = 80000 #org 80000
    sigma = 1.2 #org 1.2
    visual_multiplier = 1.0

    wls_filter = cv.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=matcher_left)
    wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
    wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

    print('computing disparity...')
    disp = matcher_left.compute(imgL, imgR).astype(np.float32) / 16
    displ = matcher_left.compute(imgL, imgR).astype(np.float32) / 16
    dispr = matcher_right.compute(imgR, imgL).astype(np.float32) / 16
    displ = np.int16(displ)
    dispr = np.int16(dispr)
    filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, imgL, None, dispr)

    # Display the result
    filteredImg = cv.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_8U);
    filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)

    #print distance

    b = 120
    f = 510

    D = b * f / d

    print (disp)

    print (D)

    plt.imshow(filteredImg, 'gray')
    plt.show()
    cv.waitKey()

    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    cv.destroyAllWindows(1)
```